# Auto disconnect on magento CMS

Tags: magento, content-management-system

When I log into my website in the CMS panel on Magento, I get disconnected after some clicks on any link.

I've Cleaned, tried another browser and reinstalled my current browser, but nothing seems to change this malfunction.

Comment: Maybe you use http and https or some links is with www and some without www? Can you give to me the url of your shop?

Comment: Thanks for your answer

the url is : http://www.cosplay-heaven.com/index.php/ and i must add the name of the cms to login

Comment: What do you do before disconnect? Maybe exists the pattern of actions which cause this problem?
I recommend you check the logs (php error log, exception.log and system.log). The redirects also can be the problems.

Comment: Well i've made a scan of malware bytes and it seems ok now, sorry for this x) and thanks for help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?